# Fourier Series and sum help

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have to find the Fourier series expansion of the function $f(x)$=$x^2$ for $-\pi <x< \pi$
and using it I have to show that,

i) $1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{25}...$ = $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

ii) $1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{16}+-...$ = $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$

I found out the Fourier expansion, it turned out to be,

$\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ - $2\left(\cos x-\frac{1}{4}\cos2x+\frac{1}{9}\cos3x-\frac{1}{16}\cos4x…\right)$

How do I proceed further, any ideas?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/324158/117818 for (i), the (ii) is more or less the same.

Comment: The "trick" is to notice what happened when $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ and when $ \ x = \ \pi \ $ .